# Time shift visualisation of time bar chart

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to create a bar chart from a prometheus counter.

With a timeshift of 14d/d I've already achieved a setting the time portion of the bar chart to 0:00. The problem is the value of (example) 2018-01-04 00:00 is the total increase of the 24 preceding hours.
Which grafana helpfully shows just after the date marker.

Is it possible to shift the bars to appear 24h-36h to the left, so the date that appears on the bottom of the graph is directly below the bar that represents those values?

[image: example]
As you can see, the bar just to the right of 12/31 looks like it would represent 1/1, but is actually the value from 12/30.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Have the same question/issue? Thx